# Need to convert latitude and longitude to UTM with specific zone in Java

Tags: java, coordinate-systems, utm

I'm having trouble converting coordinates to UTM33 (Northern Hemisphere) in Java.

I have found plenty of lat/long to UTM converters, however these determine which UTM zone the coordinates are in and give an answer accondingly. That's not what I want, I basically want to force it to use UTM zone 33.

**Example of how I want it:**

Coordinates A and B are E 100m and N 100m in UTM 31, but I would like to know their position according to UTM 33, which may be E -1000m and N -1000m UTM 33.

I don't really care if I first get the UTM 31 coordinates and then convert them to UTM 33 or if I convert the lat/long coordinates directly to UTM 33, but I can't seem to find a library which does any of these.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to use this [converter](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-coordconvert/#download) and then changed the code a little. In the class **LatLon2UTM's setVariables(double latitude, double longitude)** method I changed the zone variable **var1** to 33 and removed the calculation that calculated the real UTM zone.

original:

```
var1 = ((int) (longitude / 6)) + 31;
```

new:

```
var1 = 33;
```

Nothing great, but at least now I can convert to the zone I want!